# git/ folder not pulled on composer require

Tags: git, composer-php

We have a private server for handling repo's of projects. Now, following the procedure I've done a few times already, suddenly I've stumbled upon that "composer require" on one of these modules does not contain the `.git/` folder that should be there.

"Can happen" I thought, someone might've forgotten to include it when creating the repo. However, when going to `vendor/company/module`, remove the files, do `git init` + `git remote add origin ssh:repo.git` + `git pull`, I come across that `git add .git/` does nothing but give me the warning below:

```
$ git add .git/
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .git/FETCH_HEAD.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
error: Invalid path '.git/FETCH_HEAD'
error: unable to add .git/FETCH_HEAD to index
fatal: adding files failed
```

Thought I'd ask for if someone has an idea of how to make sure that `.git/` gets included when pulling (via `composer install/update/require`) from a Satis server.

Haven't found a solution searching SO for `[git] folder`, `[git] .git/ folder` or more variations over multiple pages of results.

Comment: A Git repository's `.git/` directory is never tracked. It gets created when you run `git clone` or `git init`. In fact, it _can't_ be tracked. Did this particular dependency come from a Git repo, or elsewhere?

Comment: One of our own git repo's. Had just never looked up why we always use the `--prefer-source` flag. Learned that now though, see my answer below. Couldn't however find how to include an automated `--prefer-source` in the composer configuration so the flag isn't necessary in the Terminal. Have you any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer comes from a colleague.

When I was installing the package, it was just for the one package. Therefore I used `composer require company/project/module` to install it.

However, when installing the whole `vendor/` folder for a project we use `composer install --prefer-source -v`.

The primary difference being the usage of `--prefer-source` as the `-v` flag just gives a more detailed (verbose) output in the Terminal.

What I should've done was `composer require company/project/module --prefer-source`

Went to look up as to why this did work; following [from the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md):

> **--prefer-source**: There are two ways of downloading a package: source and dist. For stable versions Composer will use the dist by default.
>   The source is a version control repository. If --prefer-source is
>   enabled, Composer will install from source if there is one. This is
>   useful if you want to make a bugfix to a project and get a local git
>   clone of the dependency directly.

=========================

The reverse of `--prefer-source` is `--prefer-dist`; following [from the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md)

> **--prefer-dist**: Reverse of --prefer-source, Composer will install from dist if possible. This can speed up installs substantially on build
>   servers and other use cases where you typically do not run updates of
>   the vendors. It is also a way to circumvent problems with git if you
>   do not have a proper setup.

More about setting up different sources for a package (repo) in your projects can be [found here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md).